# Generalisations of the Fundamental Theorem of Statistical Learning to different tasks and losses

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, pac-learning

The fundamental theorem of statistical learning gives an equivalence between uniform convergence of the empirical risk to learning in the PAC framework.

I have only seen this stated in the case of binary classification with the 0-1 loss.
Does a result of this form hold in more general settings? For example: margin-based classification rules, regression, multi-class classification, ...?

Another statement of this question could be: under what circumstances does uniform convergence of the empirical risk imply PAC learning? (I am most interested in this direction of implication.)

Please provide references if you have them.

Comment: Uniform convergence means that the Empirical Risk Minimizer is a PAC learner.

Comment: I take issue with your characterization of the "fundamental theorem of statistical learning". For classification, it states the equivalence of PAC learnability and finite VC-dimension.

Comment: You should probably accept your own answer so this question stops showing up in the feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is yes and can be found in Part 3 (eg chapter 19) of Neural Network Learning: Theoretical Foundations, by Anthony and Bartlett.